# I want to install PHP GTFS-realtime Language Bindings in laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to install PHP GTFS-realtime Language Bindings in laravel 5.5. But it Gives error

```
 Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/console v3.4.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.24
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.23
    - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v5.5.22
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.22
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.21
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.20
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.19
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.18
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.17
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.16
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.15
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.14
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.13
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.12
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.11
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.10
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.9
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.8
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.7
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.6
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.5
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.4
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.3
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.1
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/console v3.4.0
    - Installation request for laravel/framework 5.5.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.5.0, v5.5.1, v5.5.10, v5.5.11, v5.5.12, v5.5.13, v5.5.14, v5.5.15, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.18, v5.5.19, v5.5.2, v5.5.20, v5.5.21, v5.5.22, v5.5.23, v5.5.24, v5.5.3, v5.5.4, v5.5.5, v5.5.6, v5.5.7, v5.5.8, v5.5.9].

    - laravel/framework v5.5.0 requires symfony/console ~3.3 -> satisfiable by symfony/console[v3.3.13, v3.3.0, v3.3.1, v3.3.10, v3.3.11, v3.3.12, v3.3.14, v3.3.2, v3.3.3, v3.3.4, v3.3.5, v3.3.6, v3.3.7, v3.3.8, v3.3.9, v3.4.0, v3.4.1].
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/console v3.3.14|install symfony/console v2.8.32
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `composer global update` command

I have the same problem, I resolved this problem by removing composer.lock file & then run composer global update command.  I prefer this [link](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/composer-conflict-when-installing-valet?page=1) to resolve the issues

Comment: Thanks But it doesn't work. still, i facing same error.

Comment: I am getting File Like This code .Can you tell me how to decode this ?

{
1.0?????>m
1.0
1????
2????
3????
4????
5????
6????
7????
S?????
000001?
3
149900_1..N20171209*1?>
01 0059  SFT/242ß‘??ß‘??"104N?>
44????????"103N?>
4å”®?"101N?>
4O
000002"E
3
149900_1..N20171209*1?>
01 0059  SFT/242

Comment: which file is this?

Comment: when i run this code it gives me one file. I found this code in that file

Comment: Not sure about it, can you share more details

Comment: When I run my app it will give me one file the file have full of code as I posted above. Can you tell me how to decode this?